# sh script: wrong curl output only if assigned in a variable

Tags: curl, sh

I'm writing a sh script.

URL="https://www1.sedecatastro.gob.es/CYCBienInmueble/OVCConCiud.aspx?RefC=17005A004000880000JG&from=OVCBusqueda&del=17&mun=5"

curl -s $URL

That works fine. But I don't need to print that, I need store it in a variable. Then I do:

var=$(curl -s $URL)

But when echo $var there is another content.

This page loads dynamic info and seems when use curl with variable assignment it don't download all data.

I can do that:

curl -s $URL > file.txt

But I think this is not the correct way, the other way should work fine.

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: `echo "$var"` will work.

Comment: :- ) you're welcome! It has to do with Bash "word splitting", made worse by the fact that the HTML response there seems to be using Windows newlines `^M`. `var=$(curl -s "$URL" | dos2unix)` helped a little bit but still, to prevent word-splitting use `echo "$var"`.  Good luck!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)